# Hide a region from a specific node? (Without CSS)

Tags: theming

I can hide a region from a specific node via CSS but this is problematic since the `Display: none` attribute doesn't really clear the space... Any other way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing it via [hook_page_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_page_alter/7)

> Perform alterations before a page is rendered.
>
> Use this hook when you want to remove or alter elements at the page
>   level, or add elements at the page level that depend on an other
>   module's elements (this hook runs after hook_page_build().

You can then get the page you are on by calling [menu_get_object](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7) without parameters and inspect the returned node object.

Add this code to your theme's template.php file:

```
function MYTHEME_page_alter(&$page){
  //dpm($page);
  if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
    if ($node->nid == 72) { // pick your node or add a condition to your liking
      // remove sidebar first region
      unset($page['sidebar_first']); // remove the regeion here
    }
  }
}
```

If your theme depends on it, and depending on the region you are removing, you should also implement template_preprocess_html and adjust your body classes so that they are in sync.

As to the CSS, `dispay:none` as a css rule should remove the element from display, whereas `visibility:hidden` hides an element, but it will still take up the same space as before. [CSS Display and Visibility](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp)